# Relation between Overloading and Object Orientation

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, overloading

Is there a relation between function overloading and object orientation in C++?

And if yes, Then what is that relation?

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this question. It may not be a programming problem, but it's an important concept about programming. Maybe they think it was better suited for some other site. Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are related in the sense that one of the features of most object oriented systems is some sort of polymorphism and overloading also provides a form of polymorphism (specifically a form of ad-hoc polymorphism).

C++ provides polymorphism mostly in three ways:

- overloading (a form of ad-hoc polymorphism)
- templates (also a form of ad-hoc polymorphism)
- class inheritance (a form of subtype polymorphism due to defining each class as a type)

And it is the fact that each of these features provide some sort of polymorphism that makes them related.

Answer (score 3):

These are separate concepts.

Overloading is, as mentioned, using type to determine function.

Object Oriented Programming is the logical organization of data and function by concept of modeled thing -- often a real world thing or its abstraction.

Languages that seek to solve similar problems often provide both capabilities, but one is free to use one tool and not the other without harm.

Answer (score -1):

Function overloading is related to one of the deepest ideas in object orientation: the idea that a data type dictates how a function or operator behaves.

A related idea is that of operator overloading. An operator (such as + or -) can be applied to different data types, and the operator will do the correct thing for the types involved.

You can also write operator functions for your own types.

You can see operator overloading in the core language. Adding two integers and adding two floating-point numbers require different machine instructions.

The C++ compiler executes different low-level routines depending on the types in an expression:

```
a + b
```

If the types of the arguments change, the compiler generates different instructions.

Once again, the idea is one deeply ingrained in object orientation: The type of the data involved dictates the behavior of the function.

Yet overloading is not a full implementation of this idea. Type information may be known imperfectly at compile time. That’s where polymorphism comes into play.

Comment: It was not me to downvote you. But you are missing the target. The idea that a function may work with multiple types is not related to OO, it's the basis of polymorphism. Types dictating behavior is also just one accident of classes being types in C++, there are OO systems where objects dictate behavior without having a type at all. Your last sentence is very wrong as it implies polymorphism is separate from overloading, while overloading is in fact a form of polymorphism. Plus you concentrate on operator overloading, but C++ has overloading for much more than operators.